# Python: adding args to os.system

Tags: python, subprocess

So I am importing the "args" used on a console project and trying to add them to the cmd line but am getting "can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str".

I pull the answers to the args from the microprocessors responses which I list below:

```
level = 5
name = T7
seed = b'cd663319'

import subprocess
string="ConsoleUnlock.exe --database=database.json" + " --name="+(name) +" --level"+(level) + " --seed="+(seed)
result=subprocess.getoutput(string)
print("result::: ",result)
```

Comment: You aren't using `os.system` at all. Why is it in the title?

Comment: `seed` is a bytes object. You need to convert it with `str` - or I would suggest that you just use an `f` string to do the string formatting, and this will be done for you implicitly.

Comment: Mind, the _better_ way to do this is `subprocess.getoutput(['ConsoleUnlock.exe', '--database=database.json', f'name={name}', f'level={level}', f'--seed={str(seed)}'])` -- note that we're generating a _list_ of arguments, not a single string, which makes our command work without needing `shell=True`.

Comment: `f'--seed={seed.decode()}'` is more likely needed `--seed=b'cd6634319'` is probably not what the command needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
level = 5
name = T7
seed = 'cd663319'

import subprocess
cmd = f"ConsoleUnlock.exe --database=database.json --name={name} --level={level} --seed={seed}"
result = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
print("result::: ", result)
```

I changed `seed` to a regular string `'cd663319'` instead of a bytestring `b'cd663319'`. It doesn't seem like there is a particular need for a bytestring here. I also renamed your `string` variable to `cmd`, which is more intuitive. As others have commented, there are several other ways to improve your approach.

Comment: That's going to make `--seed=b'cd66331b'` and probably not what is needed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Okay, I removed the bytestring.

Comment: The OP *may* actually have that parameter as a byte string and not hard-coded.  `{seed.decode()}` would work in that case but OP should clarify

Comment: @AndrewEckart that worked like a charm! Thank you. Much appreciated. Now that the windows version is working, how would I convert this same code to function in linux?

Comment: @MasterCode [`subprocess.getoutput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getoutput) works on both Linux and Windows systems, so it only depends on the availability of this `ConsoleUnlock.exe` binary in your Linux environment.